# Why is Math.floor() preferred over Math.round()? [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, math, range, rounding

I found in FreeCodeCamp that to solve the problem of getting a random whole number within a range is to use `Math.floor`. It's inaccurate in rounding. It returns equal to or less than. It's not what I thought.

This is the given formula:
`Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min`

Does anyone know why it is more used for rounding to the nearest whole number?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A floor operation always rounds down, not to the nearest whole number.

Comment: [The Math.floor() function returns the largest integer less than or equal to a given number.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)

Comment: In addition, if your goal is to only round down - Floor doesn't care about decimals. There are no calculations other than a simple number comparison that just returns an integer as a result.

Comment: Your given formula is an example of [get random range, inclusive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#Getting_a_random_integer_between_two_values_inclusive), where you only want to round down using (`Math.floor()`) to keep within your range.

Answer (score 9):

Summary: Because with `Math.round()` the values in `min` and `max` are underrepresented.

---

let's have an example and compare the results when using `Math.floor()` and `Math.random()` respectively.

Just for clarity I've added the two formulas we're comparing:

```
min = 0;
max = 3;

result = Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
result = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

| result | Math.round() | Math.floor() |
|:------:|:------------:|:------------:|
|    0   |  0.0 - 0.499 |   0 - 0.999  |
|    1   |  0.5 - 1.499 |   1 - 1.999  |
|    2   |  1.5 - 2.499 |   2 - 2.999  |
|    3   |  2.5 - 2.999 |   3 - 3.999  |
```

you see that `0` and `3` have only half as big of a range that produces them with `Math.random()` than every other range in out example.

Added a snippet to show that effect:

```js
// the same random numbers for all arrays, nonone should say these would have any influence.
const randomNumbers = Array(10000).fill().map(Math.random);

//min <= random <= max
const min = 4, max = 7;

// the +1 is to do `random <= max` otherwise it would produce `random < max`
const floored = randomNumbers.map(random => Math.floor(random * (max - min + 1) + min));

const rounded = randomNumbers.map(random => Math.round(random * (max - min) + min));

//utility to count the number of occurances per value
const count = (acc, nr) => (acc[nr] = (acc[nr] || 0) + 1, acc);

console.log({
  "Math.floor()": floored.reduce(count, {}),
  "Math.round()": rounded.reduce(count, {})
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I was just wondering where or how did you find this reference? @Thomas

Comment: @UnorthodoxThing what reference? I knew the problem from personal experience and made an example to demonstrate it.

Comment: Seriously? You should documented it or file a report! o.o

Comment: Document what? That `Math.round()` may round up, but `Math.floor()` does not? The mentioned "problem" is that `Math.round()` is not siuted for this job, because of the reasons I've explained in this answer. There is nothing wrong any of the used methods themselves.

Comment: So to be clear, Math.round is only an issue when used with Math.random? I see Math.floor preferred often even when Math.random isn't used, in cases where I presume Math.round would actually be more accurate because it rounds to the nearest integer instead of just rounding down.

Answer (score 2):

This is the real reason, at least the way I see it, Math.random returns a float number between 0 (Included) and 1 (Not included), something like 0 - 0.9999999999999999 (I assume). Looking at this information we can easily think, ok, this is a percentage, so all We have to do is something like:

```
    let max = 10;

    console.log(Math.round(Math.random() * max))
```

Right?, Well, let's take a look at what our Math.random number should really represent in our range.

Let's say our range is **min=1** and **max=5**, that creates five different possibilities: 1,2,3,4,5. If 0.9999999999999999, or 1 for simplicity, is the maximum number you can get from Math.random, we can divide it into the number of possibilities our range has, something like 1 / max, getting roughly 0.2 as the result, this means each possibility will be at least equal to this number multiplied by it's value, that said Math.random values in the following ranges would satisfy each possibility:

| From | To | Expected Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.2 | 1 |
| 0.21 | 0.4 | 2 |
| 0.41 | 0.6 | 3 |
| 0.61 | 0.8 | 4 |
| 0.81 | 0.9999999999999999 | 5 |

Now let's look at what Math.round does:

```
    console.log(0.25 * 5, 'rounded to:', Math.round(0.25 * 5));
    //Prints 1.25 'rounded to:' 1
    
    console.log(0.31 * 5, 'rounded to:', Math.round(0.31 * 5));
    //Prints 1.55 'rounded to:' 2

    console.log(0.85 * 5, 'rounded to:', Math.round(0.85 * 5));
    //Prints 4.25 'rounded to:' 4
```

**As you can see, in some situations (The floats for your min and the floats for you max) Math.round won't return the result we might be expecting**, like in the first example, we were expecting 2 because 0.25 is greater than 0.2 and in the last example we were expecting 5 because 0.85 is greater than 0.8. This means that every float from 0.21 to 0.299999999999999 and from 0.81 to 0.899999999999999 will result in unexpected results, and this is why a Math.floor solution is preferred.

How about we divide our randomly generated float by our fixed possibility float?

```
    console.log(0.25 / (1 / 5));//Prints 1.25
    console.log(0.31 / (1 / 5));//Prints 1.5499999999999998
    console.log(0.85 / (1 / 5));//Prints 4.25
```

If you look at these results, they can be fixed by rounding them down and making sure we at least get the min value by adding the min value at the end:

```
    let min = 1;
    let max = 5;
    let r = Math.random();
    let f = 1 / max;
    let x = Math.floor(r / f) + min;

    console.log(r, x);
```

Now We have another problem, if We change our min value to any number other than 1, we need to adjust our formula to cover the offset created in the number of possibilities. So if our range changed to **min=2** and **max=5** We now have four possibilities: 2,3,4,5 and our formula now includes (max - min + 1) to calculate de number of possibilities; The + 1 makes the range inclusive creating the slot needed for the four possibilities:

```
    let min = 2;
    let max = 5;
    let r = Math.random();
    let f = 1 / (max - min + 1);
    let x = Math.floor(r / f) + min;

    console.log(r, x);
```

Our final function would look like this:

```
    const randomNumber = (min, max) => {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() / (1 / (max - min + 1))) + min;
    }
    
    console.log(randomNumber(2, 5));
    
    //If Math.random ever returns 0.999999999999999
    console.log(Math.floor(0.999999999999999 / (1 / (5 - 2 + 1))) + 2);//Prints 5
    
    console.log(Math.floor(0.249999999999999 / (1 / (5 - 2 + 1))) + 2);//Print 2

    //Hope this never happens
    console.log(Math.floor(0.25 / (1 / (5 - 2 + 1))) + 2);//Print 3
```

Which is the same as:

```
    const randomNumber = (min, max) => {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
    
    console.log(randomNumber(2, 5));
    
    //If Math.random ever returns 0.999999999999999
    console.log(Math.floor(0.999999999999999 * (5 - 2 + 1)) + 2);//Prints 5
    
    console.log(Math.floor(0.249999999999999 * (5 - 2 + 1)) + 2);//Print 2

    //Hope this never happens
    console.log(Math.floor(0.25 * (5 - 2 + 1)) + 2);//Print 3
```

Comment: So to be clear, `Math.round` is only an issue when used with `Math.random`? I see `Math.floor` preferred often even when `Math.random` isn't used, in cases where I presume `Math.round` would actually be more accurate because it rounds to the nearest integer instead of just rounding down.

Comment: I don't know about other cases, however I should clarify that it's not about Math.floor, it's actually Math.floor + 1 or Math.ceil. Imagine you have a range 1-3, that's 1,2,3; Each number should have the same number of opportunities, that means each number should have a 33.33% chance or 0.3333333, so if Math.random returns any float between 0.34-0.66, the expected result should be 2 because 0.34 is greater than 0.3333333, right? 0.34*3=1.02, Math.round would round it down to 1 while Math.floor would do exactly the same, but the +1 would fix the result. Now test any float between 0.34-0.49

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min
```

will give you a random number in the range of [min, max] because Math.random() gives you [0, 1). Let's use Math.round instead of Math.floor, Math.random() gives you [0, 1) and if you multiply it by 10, you will get [0, 10). This is a floating point and if you round it up, you will get [0, 10] as integer. However, if you round it down, you will get [0, 10) as integer.

In most random function, the norm is to return [min, max).

To answer your question, the author uses Math.floor so that the random number will be in the range of [min, max] instead of [min, max+1] if using Math.round.

> FROM WIKIPEDIA

Intervals
Main article: Interval (mathematics)
Both parentheses, ( ), and square brackets, [ ], can also be used to denote an interval. The notation {\displaystyle [a,c)} [a, c) is used to indicate an interval from a to c that is inclusive of {\displaystyle a} a but exclusive of {\displaystyle c} c. That is, {\displaystyle [5,12)} [5, 12) would be the set of all real numbers between 5 and 12, including 5 but not 12. The numbers may come as close as they like to 12, including 11.999 and so forth (with any finite number of 9s), but 12.0 is not included. In some European countries, the notation {\displaystyle [5,12[} [5,12[ is also used for this.

Answer (score 0):

`Math.floor(Math.random())` will always return `0` while `Math.round(Math.random())` will return `0 or 1` thus with the `Math.round()` the random numbers will follow a non-uniform distribution. Which may not be acceptable for your needs.